# Java Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ipconfig/release"); returns error?

Tags: java, runtime, ipconfig

I want to disconnect my computer from the internet, and the best way that I can think of, is running the ipconfig/release from the cmd. To do so, I did

```
 Process result = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ipconfig/release");
```

This throws an error however,

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "ipconfig/release": CreateProcess error=
2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
        at threadio.run(checkmac.java:141)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find th
e file specified
```

Which I am not sure what means.

Any ideads what I'm doing wrong? Any better alternatives to disconnect from the router?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `ipconfig /release` (note the space), also, generally speaking, it's usually easier to use `ProcessBuilder` and separate each command and parameter as it's own argument `new ProcessBuilder("ipconfig", "/release");`

Comment: @MadProgrammer If you are on Windows, try `ipconfig/release"` from the command line

Comment: The Windows command line has bug-compatible behavior that splits tokens on slashes. I doubt that the Windows equivalent of `exec` does the same.

Comment: It was the space that did it, thanks. It's weird though, it works without the space if I type it directly in cmd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with a space

```
Process result = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ipconfig /release");
```

Comment: You can try with this also C:/Windows/System32/ipconfig.exe /release,, giving complete path of the ipconfig

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that ipconfig.exe is in the PATH, then Runtime.exec is capable of finding it, if it is not, you will need to supply the fully qualified path to it.